Select nearest neighbour by group in R
I have two sets of coordinates, where each pair of coordinates belongs to a group. I'd like to use st_connect to identify the nearest neighbour, but within the group (i.e. nearest neighbour within "A" and "B", respectively). Is there any way to do that other than split the datasets and apply st_connect seperately to each group?
library(nngeo)
library(sf)
dat_1 <- data.frame(lat = c(47.19384, 48.19342, 50.98793),
                    lon = c(8.13712, 8.50274, 7.27492),
                    group = c("A", "A", "B")) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lat', 'lon'), remove = TRUE) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) 

dat_2 <- data.frame(lat = c(48.87463, 47.29572, 49.01849),
           lon = c(9.82713, 7.56294, 8.49194),
           group = c("A", "B", "B")) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lat', 'lon'), remove = TRUE) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) 

nngeo::st_connect(dat_1, dat_2)


I can't see a way to do it without splitting and subsetting, unless there's a way to run a spatial SQL query within sf... Anyway, the split and subset approach isn't too hard:
nnLines <- 
function(d1, d2, gname="group"){
  do.call(
    c,lapply(
      split(d1,d1[[gname]]), 
      function(d){st_connect(d, d2[d2[[gname]]==d[[gname]][1],])}
    )
   )
}


nn1 = nnLines(dat_1, dat_2)

This code might have trouble if, for example, there's no matching group in dat_2 for some value in dat_1. Also it doesn't preserve the ordering, it just returns the lines in group ordering but not guarantee of ordering within groups.
Check that all dat_1 points are connected to the nearest dat_2 of the same group:
plot(c(dat_1$geom, dat_2$geom),pch="")
plot(dat_1$geom, col=as.factor(dat_1$group), pch="1",add=TRUE)
plot(dat_2$geom, col=as.factor(dat_2$group), pch="2",add=TRUE)
plot(nn1, add=TRUE)


